# Cross platform installer tools

Tags: installation, wix, install4j, installanywhere

In our dev team we use .net core, java and C++. We need to deploy our product to windows and linux. The installation is not simple and need to configure web application, services, config files, shortcuts etc.

I have found product like [InstallAnywhere](https://www.flexera.com/producer/products/software-installation/installanywhere/) , [INSTALL4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) , [installbuilder](https://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) and [izpack](http://izpack.org/downloads/).

What are the best tool for the job?

Comment: Unfortunately, tool recommendations are not allowed on stackoverflow, they are usually downvoted and closed. I could write up something for install4j, but since the site does not want these answers, I'll refrain from doing so.

Comment: This topic has me confused as well. [Some thoughts here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624645/129130) (but no answer). Never tried izpack.