# How to create an installer for a .Net service that takes inputs and install prerequisites automatically

Tags: .net, installation

i want to create an installation interface for a service , that takes input from users and install prerequisites like .Net framework exct ...

i have tried WIX but it was too complecated and did fulfill my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***General Links***: Some deployment tools information:

- [**Quick Tools Overview**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) - the leading MSI tools.
- In case you want to compare the tools here is [**an old comparative answer - tools review**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941).

> I would try [**Advanced Installer**](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) based on your comments. There is a very nice [**Advanced Installer Help Portal**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29130) available with links to help material of all kinds.
>
> ***Service***: Here are some tutorials on service installation - of various types:
>
> - [Installing Windows Services](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/installing-windows-services.html)
> - [How to Install Services](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-service.html)
> - [Node.js web app deployed as a Windows service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiD3ECIqPdI)

***Video Tutorials***: And finally here are video tutorials of all kinds: https://www.youtube.com/user/AdvancedInstaller/videos

---

***Further Info***: Stefan Kruger's comprehensive bists on installsite.org:

- ***Non-MSI installer tools***: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_nonmsi.htm
- ***Windows installer tools***: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm

And just for reference: [Does an universal cross-platform installer exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619358/does-an-universal-cross-platform-installer-exists/51624645#51624645) (non-MSI tools).

Comment: Great, welcome to the community. You can set it accepted if it helped. You will need some more up-votes before you get more privileges on the site.

Comment: i get this error when i finish using advanced installer  :Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A winwows Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Afministrative tool or the NET START command.

Comment: i was using this command to run my sevice : installutil /u "D:\MyService\MyService\MyService.net\MyService\bin\Debug\MyService.exe" , it worked fine but after using the installer it didnt work , dunno why

Comment: Generally you need a new question for follow-ups like that - in order for answers to be found by others. If you register a service correctly via MSI you should not need `installutil.exe` - this involves using the MSI service installation and control tables. This should happen auto-magically is you follow standard approaches shown here: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/installing-windows-services.html.

Comment: [General debugging of launch failures - links down the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130). And finally the direct link to: [Launch Problem Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530377/129130). Oh, and the [Windows Services Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html)

Comment: thanks , ill do that next time , ill take a look at what you sent me