# How to create windows installer for ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, windows-installer, software-distribution

I am trying to create a windows installer for a web application. In this web project we are using both front-end (ReactJS) and back-end (Spring BOOT) servers.

Now I am struggling to create a installer for the software distribution:

1. Can someone please advice me how to do it?
2. How to approach to start those servers once installed?

Comment: [Tools list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). All I have time for before heading out. [Throwing in this link too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609287/129130). Not a 100% match.

Comment: [A direct link to this video from **Advanced Installer** on **Node.js web app**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiD3ECIqPdI). Though not entirely on topic, worth a watch. Just a couple of minutes. [And one for Electron apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gofqp4PfWPc).