# Searching for Platform independent installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer, dotnetinstaller, appinstaller

Would anyone happen to know if there are any platform independent installer options that can be used for both windows and Linux?

Comment: Least-worst I have is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624645/129130). It has not been updated for a while.

Comment: So I found the NSIS installer.  Is there any other options?